# Linearly independent rows and matrices $2$

Tags: linear-algebra

True or false: If $A$ has linearly independent rows then it forms a basis for $\text{Row}(A)$?

Comment: does that $Row(A)$ mean rowspace of $A$? Yes, it is true.

Comment: @HirakjyotiDas Be careful: as stated, this is a bit of a trick question. The matrix $A$ does *not* (and *can*not) form a basis for its row space; the *rows* of $A$ treated as vectors do.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $\mbox{Row} A$, the row space of $A$, is the space spanned by the rows (considered as vectors) so the set of the row vectors spans the row space by definition! When do you call a set a *basis*...?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the matrix $A \in R^{nxn}$ and you have $n$ linearly independent rows then the rows form a basis for the $R^n$ space. If this is the case then you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The statement *as written* is false. The matrix $A$ does not (and cannot) be a basis for its row space. On the other hand, the *rows* of $A$, considered as vectors, if linearly independent *do* form a basis for the row space.

If this is exactly as the problem was posed to you, then perhaps it’s a trick question designed to test your understanding of the nuances of these definitions.